# Vue 3 template refs does not really reflect actual DOM state

Tags: arrays, vue.js

I am creating a website for planning out study timetables.

I am now creating an `Add/Remove subject` section where user can add, edit or remove the `Subject` containing `id` and `name`, all the subjects user have added will be represented as a list of `<input>`s so users can easily edit them, and stored as an array of objects (`Array<{ id: string, name: string }>`).

I have some criteria that I wanted the list to behave when user edits the key (subject ID) whether the added one or the one they're adding.

- If you add new `Subject` with the same `id` but different `name`, you will be editing that `name` in the list.
- If you edit the `Subject` that you've added to the array. When you change its `id`, if the `id` that you've changed is the same as the other one, the old one will get deleted. for example.

```js
const subjectList = [
  { id: 'B2205', name: 'Business 1' },
  { id: 'B2210', name: 'Internship' },
  { id: 'U1539', name: 'Undergraduate Thesis' }
]
// User edits the id from B2210 to B2205, the array will become
const subjectList = [
  { id: 'B2205', name: 'Internship' },
  { id: 'U1539', name: 'Undergraduate Thesis' }
]
```

The problem that I am having is that I am trying to implement a feature where on the second criteria. When the `id` is changed and the duplicate is deleted. I wanted to call `HTMLInputElement.focus()` on the `<input>` so users can continue editing without leaving the keyboard.

I approached the problem by using [Template Refs with `v-for`](https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/composition-api-template-refs.html#usage-inside-v-for). I created 2 variables called `subjects` storing `Subject` object that users have created, and `subjectRefs` to act as reference to each `<input>` that I'm going to generate using `v-for`. This solution works as expected when adding new subject. but when I delete the subject. value in `subjects` gets deleted *but in `subjectRefs`, it does not get deleted.* It stays the same length as before. I logged out the value and sees this.

```
// Initial
subjects | subjectRefs
[]         []

// Add { id: 'A1', name: 'A' }
subjects                   | subjectRefs
[                          | [
  { id: 'A1', name: 'A' }  |   HTMLInputElement.value = 'A1'
]
                          | ]
// Add { id: 'B1', name: 'B' }
subjects                   | subjectRefs
[                          | [
  { id: 'A1', name: 'A' }  |   HTMLInputElement.value = 'A1'
  { id: 'B1', name: 'B' }  |   HTMlInputElement.value = 'B1' 
]                          | ]

// Remove { id: 'B1', name: 'B' }
subjects                   | subjectRefs
[                          | [
  { id: 'A1', name: 'A' }  |   HTMLInputElement.value = 'A1'
]                          |   HTMlInputElement.value = 'B1' 
                           | ]

// Add { id: 'C1', name: 'C' }
subjects                   | subjectRefs
[                          | [
  { id: 'A1', name: 'A' }  |   HTMLInputElement.value = 'A1'
  { id: 'C1', name: 'C' }  |   HTMlInputElement.value = 'C1' 
]                          | ]

// Remove { id: 'A1', name: 'A' }
subjects                   | subjectRefs
[                          | [
  { id: 'C1', name: 'C' }  |   HTMLInputElement.value = 'C1'
]                          |   HTMlInputElement.value = 'C1'
                           | ]

// Add { id: 'A1', name: 'A' } and { id: 'B2', name: 'B' }
subjects                   | subjectRefs
[                          | [
  { id: 'C1', name: 'C' }  |   HTMLInputElement.value = 'C1'
  { id: 'A1', name: 'A' }  |   HTMlInputElement.value = 'A1'
  { id: 'B2', name: 'B' }  |   HTMLInputElement.value = 'B2'
]                          | ]

// Edit { id: 'C1', name: 'C' } to { id: 'C9', name: 'C' }
subjects                   | subjectRefs
[                          | [
  { id: 'C9', name: 'C' }  |   HTMLInputElement.value = 'C9'
  { id: 'A1', name: 'A' }  |   HTMlInputElement.value = 'A1'
  { id: 'B2', name: 'B' }  |   HTMLInputElement.value = 'B2'
]                          | ]

// Remove { id: 'C9', name: 'C' } and { id: 'A1', name: 'A' }
subjects                   | subjectRefs
[                          | [
  { id: 'B2', name: 'B' }  |   HTMLInputElement.value = 'B2'
]                          |   HTMlInputElement.value = 'B2'
                           |   HTMLInputElement.value = 'B2'
                           | ]
```

It doesn't look like the `subjectRefs` are updating its value, I don't know if manually manipulating the `ref` array will be bad thing or not.

I have provided a codesandbox for you guys [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/competent-frost-xdn8z?file=/src/App.vue) but the logs won't let you see that deep. If you have any more questions or requirements please let me know. Thank you.

Comment: Please share some code, that may help

Comment: @AbdullahKhan OP linked the code here ==> https://codesandbox.io/s/competent-frost-xdn8z?file=/src/App.vue

Comment: Oh my bad. Thanks been looking too loosely

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably you can change your `removeSubject` function like this i.e add code to remove from subjectRefs as well

```
   const removeSubject = (index) => {
      try {
        subjects.value.splice(index, 1);
        subjectRefs.value.splice(index, 1);
      } catch (e) {
        throw new Error("Cannot convert 'key' to number.");
      }
      console.log(subjects.value, subjectRefs.value);
    };
```

I guess you were expecting that it would be automatically removed on re render, but that doesn't happen in your code. Have a look in comments in your code below

```
 <div
      v-else
      class="new-subject"
      v-for="(subject, i) in subjects" <!--- rerenders everytime subjects changes However vue will not re-render those elements for which key is same -->
      :key="`render-subject-${i}`"
    >
      <input
        class="subject-id-input"
        type="text"
        :ref="
          (el) => {
            if (el != null) subjectRefs[i] = el; <!--- Once set, none of its entry will be deleted unless done manually -->
          }
        "
        :value="subject.id"
        @input="editSubject(i, $event?.target.value, 'ID')"
      />
      <input
        class="subject-name-input"
        type="text"
        :value="subject.name"
        @input="editSubject(i, $event?.target.value, 'ID')"
      />
      <button class="add-subject-button" @click="removeSubject(i)">
        Remove
      </button>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. But I'm still a little bit skeptical about how I have to manipulate refs myself. But I'll do it like how you advised me for now until I find a better solution. Thank you.